# Which kind of resources are protected by a QMutex?

Tags: qt

I found some information about QMutex and the information said it is a synchronization tool for protecting resources. What resources does it protect?

Comment: Do you know about [Mutual exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) ?

Comment: I just getting started with the thread, so there are a lot of places do not quite understand.  thank you  everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMutex will protect the value of an object (like a variable in the example below) from being changed so that only 1 thread can access it at a time.

```
bank_account_mutex.lock();
account_balance = account_balance + money_change;
bank_account_mutex.unlock();
```

I would also recommend reading the documentation and practicing this on your own.  It is an important concept especially when you have multiple users making changes to the same data.

Answer (score 2):

The Qt documentation is quite good. You should spend some time reading it before asking such general questions as this.

Start here for `QMutex` specifically: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html

`QMutexLocker` is a closely related class that simplifies using `QMutex`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutexlocker.html

Look here for more general discussion about threads in Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

Comment: I am a beginner, Thank you for helping me